# ReactJS : use state is not working for only one state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I just don't know why it isn't working. here are my states.

```
    const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([])
    const [artist, setArtist] = useState([])
    const [artistImages, setArtistImages] = useState([])
```

and here I'm setting the states.

```
     axios.get(`/music/api/artist/1/`)
            .then(res => {
                setAlbums(res.data.albums);
                setArtist(res.data);
                setArtistImages(res.data.about_images);
                console.log(res.data.albums)
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
```

this is the response I'm getting from server

```
   BgImage: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/001_3uKSvDp.jpg"
   about_images: Array(1)
   0: {id: 1, image1: 
   "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/1034349_xl06j1h.jpg", 
   image2: null, image3: null, image4: null, …}
   length: 1
   __proto__: Array(0)
   albums: Array(3)
   0: {id: 1, album_name: "Fearless (Taylor's Version)", artwork: 
  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/001.jpg", artist: "Taylor Swift"}
   1: {id: 7, album_name: "Reputation", artwork: 
   "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/001_1.jpg", artist: "Taylor Swift"}
   2: {id: 8, album_name: "1989", artwork: 
   "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/002.jpg", artist: "Taylor Swift"}
   length: 3
   __proto__: Array(0)
   artist_name: "Taylor Swift"
   born: "1989-12-13"
   id: 1
   image: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/011.jpg"
```

problem I'm having is only `setAlbums` does not get set. all other states set like `setArtist` `setArtistImages` just Album does not set. and even if I `console.log(res.data.albums)` it returns the album. but setAlbum does not work. I just don't know why....

Comment: can you paste the complete response

Comment: Some additional code context may also be helpful.

Comment: try console logging the state outside of the http request

Comment: if I directly console out state after and outside http request. it gives an empty array. that's what i'm saying it's not setting state

Comment: @AmishaMundra That's not what you should do . You should check the updated state once you set it. Also state updates are queued so you might not get it immediatly after setting. There are different way to handle this type of update;

Comment: @programoholic yes I'm using the state after. but still it's empty

Comment: @AmishaMundra Please checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) for more about why you may not see state updates immediately after setting them. "After" is not clear on if you're checking the updates at a correct place.

Comment: How are you verifying or validating that *some* state just didn't update? You could try console logging your state values in an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on *that* specific chunk of state. If the enqueued value is different than current state it should update and trigger a rerender.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
axios.get(`/music/api/artist/1/`)
            .then(res => {
                const newAlbums = [...albums].concat(res.data.albums)
                setAlbums(newAlbums);
                setArtist(res.data);
                setArtistImages(res.data.about_images);
                console.log(res.data.albums)
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
```

Comment: yessss... and it does have the albums. just not setting the state

Comment: This isn't an answer, just seeking clarification. Please use the comments for this type of communication.

Comment: I don't have enough REPUTATION to comment. sry

Comment: I understand that can be frustrating, but it doesn't mean the rules change

Comment: how about now is this an awswer ?

Comment: Yes, now it would be considered an answer. However, I would suggest adding specifically *what* you are suggesting to try instead of just a code block, and *why* you expect it to solve their problem. Here are some additional tips on [writing a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for your reference.

Comment: Also just for info: [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) does not mutate the original array, so the spread (`[...albums]`) is not necessary.

Comment: oh yes you are right and thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233337/discussion-between-amir-hossein-and-brian-thompson).